# how to find the width and height of an image in image extention in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have used used image extension to resize the image. Its working fine. Here is the Code

```
 $image = Yii::app()->image->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/files/galaryimages/'.$fileName);
 $image->resize(900, 600)->quality(75)->sharpen(20);
 $image->save();
```

but I need  to resize only if the image size is greater than a fixed width and height How can I do this?
  
 http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/#hh5

Comment: You can probably get the width and height like `$image->width();` and `$image->height();` respectively. ***[Here is the Reference](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/image#get)***

Comment: @ThinkDifferent getting  Fatal error: Call to undefined method Image::width()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the below code

```
list($width1, $height1, $type1, $attr1) = getimagesize(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/files/images/'.$fileName);
 if(($width1>$width) || ($height1>$height))
 { 
     //code to resize 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access them by the `width` and `height` attributes:

```
echo $image->width . 'x' . $image->height;
```